# How often shall we reindex the geospatial data in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, indexing, geospatial

I wonder if it is a must of reindexing the geospatial data in mongodb if there are some new geo-data has been inserted in order to search them? Say we have a document,which looks like:
`{user:'a',loc:[363.236,-45.365]}`, and it is indexed. Later on, I inserted document b, which looks like: `{user:'b',loc:{42.3654,-56.3}}`. In order to search, do I have to reindex (using ensureIndex()) the collection every time when a new document is inserted? Will the frequent reindexing affect the overall application performance?
Thanks.

Comment: MongoDB maintains indexes for you

Comment: Do I have to use ensureIndex() every time before I search for a location?

Comment: No as I said once you make an index MongoDB will maintain it for you

Comment: Just an additional question:Say I have a document, which looks like: {loc:{start:[x,y],end:[x1,y1]}} with 2dsphere index, and I want to search for all the documents that have the same start and end points using one query. Is it possible to do it in mongodb?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only need to ensureIndex once; after that MongoDB maintains the index on every insert. I'm not 100% sure the index is maintained for deletes though - I imagine it must do.

You can defragment an index and rebuild it to make it smaller, hence the existence of the functionality. A useful post:

http://jasonwilder.com/blog/2012/02/08/optimizing-mongodb-indexes/